# How to avoid github ssh authentication problem that happens every time?

Tags: macos, github, ssh-keys

I used the vscode and install git in the system on mac. And registered the ssh key in GitHub and the device. By the way, when I `git clone` or `git push, pull` I have to register every time like this
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` even though I pull the public repository. When I work in the windows system in the past I don't get this status. I hope someone helps me to avoid this. Here `id_rsa` is the ssh key file for github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured GitHub in ~/.ssh/config?

The config should include something like this:

```
Host github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User <your-github-username>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

You can also use the `AddKeysToAgent yes` setting for the host, if you want the SSH Agent to remember the password of your SSH key, so you only have to enter it when using it the first time after every login.

If you want to pull from a public repository, you can avoid working with SSH keys, if you use HTTPS instead of SSH (note that this would require password authentication if you want to push).

Comment: Thank you. I made the config file and added the contents above and it acts well.